# Ignore Case Sensitive in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
 Dim query = CsteList.Where(Function(i) i.Text.Contains(FilterTextBox.Text.Trim))
```

1. FilterTextBox.Text = "HELLO"
2. FilterTextBox.Text = "hello"
3. FilterTextBox.Text = "HeLLo"

whether input as "HELLO" or "hello" my code should filter respective word

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Comment: If you don't use .Net Core 2.1+ or .Net 5 (which provide a new StringComparison overload to Compare(String)), you can use something like: `Dim query = CsteList.FirstOrDefault(Function(item) item.Text.IndexOf(FilterTextBox.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >=0)`